# Explain System.Reflection.MemberInfo.Name property

Tags: c#, properties, system.reflection

I'm new to C#, so this is kind of hard for me to understand. `System.Reflection.MemberInfo.Name` property is stated as follows:

`public abstract string Name { get; }`

I understand that it is an auto-implemented property, but how the value of `Name` is set in the first place?

Comment: It's not an auto-implemented property. It's abstract, so there is no implementation defined. Subclasses must define their own implementation.

Comment: `System.Reflection.ParameterInfo.Name` property is stated like this: `public virtual string Name { get; }`

Comment: That's the interface. MSDN does not give you the implementation. If you want to peek into the actual code, look at [referencesource.microsoft.com](http://referencesource.microsoft.com)

Comment: Thanks for directing me to the right place. The `Name` property returns `NameImpl` field, which in turn holds the actual value. I was confusing MSDN interface for actual implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`MemberInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Reflection.MemberInfo.aspx) is an [abstract](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf985hc5.aspx) class, which means it cannot be instantiated itself, only subclasses of it can be. That allows for some of its members to also be abstract, and the `Name` property is one.

Subclasses of `MemberInfo` must define a public property called `Name` with a public `get` accessor. How the accessor is defined is up to the subclass.

All you have to know is that any class which inherits from `MemberInfo` will provide you with a `Name` property that you can access.

Here's an example of two classes which inherit from an abstract class with an abstract property.

```
abstract class Base {
    public abstract string Name { get; }
}

class Derived1 : Base {
    public override string Name { get { return "Foobar"; } }
}

class Derived2 : Base {
    private string _name;
    public override string Name { get { return _name; } }
    public Derived2(string name) { _name = name; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`MemberInfo` is a base class for others such as `PropertyInfo`. Derived classes override `Name`. You as a user of the reflection framework do not care that this is an `abstract` property. The `Name` is simply available for you to use.

Whether this is an auto-property or not is irrelevant and in fact you cannot find out. Auto-properties are a C# concept that disappears when compiled to IL.

The .NET Reflection system allows user code to derive their own classes from the typical reflection classes such as `PropertyInfo`. The framework provides default implementations. These default implementations (here: `internal class RuntimePropertyInfo`) provide an implementation for `abstract` members.

I'm not aware of anyone doing this or using this facility. It seems like a bad idea. I consider this to be a design bug in the .NET Framework.